# The if statement does not execute even when I enter the value "d"

Tags: java, android-studio

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_story);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");

        if (name == "d")
        {
            name = "Spike";
        }

        TextView heading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.storyTextView);
        heading.setText("And our story begins with " + name);
```

Comment: You can't really compare strings usings == sign (this is the way to compare their references. Use it like this: "d".equals(name)

Comment: If you had used "Angel" instead of Spike, it would've worked. Just kidding, check the comments above about what's really wrong.